# Multiple case statement in merge statement of oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, merge

I am posting a part of my working merge statement as shown below where I am setting 10 for `MWAN,MGWAN,MWLAN,MLAN,DDOS ,mss` else 20

```
MERGE INTO table2 a
USING table1 b ON (a.second_name = b.first_name)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET a.friendly_name = TRIM(b.friendly_name),
    a.account_number  = TRIM(b.account_no),
    a.ne_type         = TRIM(b.ci_type),
    a.service_type_id = CASE
                        WHEN upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MGWAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWLAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MLAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%DDOS%'
                             OR trim(b.first_name) LIKE 'mss%'
                          THEN 10 ELSE 20 END,
```

my new requirement is if `DDOS` appears set it to 30,so the following change is sufficient

```
 MERGE INTO table2 a
    USING table1 b ON (a.second_name = b.first_name)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET a.friendly_name = TRIM(b.friendly_name),
        a.account_number  = TRIM(b.account_no),
        a.ne_type         = TRIM(b.ci_type),
        a.service_type_id = CASE
                            WHEN upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWAN%'
                                 OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MGWAN%'
                                 OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWLAN%'
                                 OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MLAN%'



                                 OR trim(b.first_name) LIKE 'mss%'
                                   THEN 10 
                            WHEN upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%DDOS%' 
                                   THEN 30
                            ELSE
                                        20
                            END.
```

I dont have oracle sql developer now, i will test later ,but what ever my guess work is correct?or any syntax error `CASE` block

Comment: Looks fine except for the period after `END`. Technically you're not looking at a CASE statement - that's a [CASE expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm#i1033392). Best of luck.

Comment: Looks fine to me too. You don't need to trim when you compare with LIKE and the comparison string is wrapped in %...% - right?